# Is there an iPad PDF viewer that can stay zoomed out?

Tags: ipad, applications, software-recommendation, pdf

Some PDFs have fonts that are too large to maintain an optimal reading speed.  Is there a normal page-scrolling (not flipping) PDF viewer that can stay zoomed out at the zoom level you've pinched to?  Everything I have tried so far automatically zooms back to 100% after releasing the pinch-zoom.

Comment: My stupid workaround right now involves [padding PDF files to add margins](https://gist.github.com/ivan/0356a4d7a39996153102990785d5a4c2).

Comment: [Documents 5 by Readdle](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/documents-by-readdle/id364901807?mt=8) does this... has page flipping tho where you have to slide across the screen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found two apps that can do this:

(free) [MarginNote](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/marginnote/id769389582) has a vertical scrolling mode (though it's not the default) and can stay zoomed out at about 50%.

(requires IAP subscription for this option) [PDF Viewer](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/pdf-viewer-annotation-expert/id1120099014) by PSPDFKit GmbH has a vertical scrolling mode (though it's not the default) and can stay zoomed out at about 50% (Settings -> Advanced -> Extended Zoom Out)

Answer (score 1):

Found this thread, by searching for an answer to the same problem.

By Providence, I did find an alternate app, which accomplishes this ability to "zoom out" (to less than 100%, etc.), on a PDF.

However, it can tend to be somewhat tricky — but not at all impossible — to get the file into the app, in the first place.

(You'll figure it out, if you have enough initiative to download the app, and to tinker around, with it).

Here is the name of the app:
"***[PDF Editor ,PDF Book Reader](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pdf-editor-pdf-book-reader/id1354910662?mt=8)***" by Milad Fakhr

I hope that helps!...

Comment: Your answer would benefit if you would add some details about how to get files into the app, especially if it is tricky any you already figured it out. It would also make the answer look less like an advertisment.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve just discovered this problem and the best solution I’ve found is using the iOS app ‘Goodnotes’ from the App Store. I’ve imported the offending .pods and not only can I now scale the reading I can also annotate with the Apple Pencil and re-export in a ton of different formats.

Really elegant bit of software. It’s a [paid program](https://www.goodnotes.com/pricing) but is absolutely worth every cent.